# Excel: How to sum values based on a calculation instead of range?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I struggle finding a way to create a formula that can sum data based on a calculated value instead of a range.

Below is a simple on what im trying to achieve:

```
Task_Name   User    Start_Date  End_Date
Task_A  Peter   01/09/2016  28/10/2016
Task_B  Peter   01/09/2016  05/09/2016


Total days for September
Peter   25
```

I need a formula that can calculate the 25 days if the inputs is september. If i use october as input it should sum all days within the period that is in october.

I use below formula to get the working day pr. task:

```
=MAX(NETWORKDAYS(MAX($C2,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1)),MIN($D2,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))))),0)
```

where:

```
$B$9 = 01/09/2016
```

That formula calculates correctly 22days for the first task.

I was thinking to do something like:

```
{=SUM(MAX(NETWORKDAYS(MAX($C2:$C3,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1)),MIN($D2:$D3,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))))),0))}
```

Above is not working and i have been playing with different options but cant crack the code - yet :)

Looking forward for some inputs.

**Edit:**

Helper columns are not preferred, as it will make my worksheet extremely complex.

/Thomas

Comment: I do not understand why people do not like helper columns or "mid calculation columns" etc. They are vital if you try to build something complex. If you have a complex formula that is several rows high and something stops working, it will be impossible to find the problem. If the calculation was broken down in smaler steps you could easily see where the problem is. Also... Pulling left on the helper column makes is disapear. Or you create a calculations sheet. All calculations are made on sheet 2 and you just link the finnished value to the main sheet.

Comment: @pnuts exactly! There is always room for calculations, and they can always be hidden.

Comment: Rule of thumb - if formula is longer than your thumb, it's too long!

Comment: You would have to replace the MIN and MAX functions with equivalent IF statements to make it work as an array formula. Unfortunately there is another problem - NETWORKDAYS doesn't seem to like arrays - so you may be stuck with a helper column.

Answer (score 0):

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(NETWORKDAYS(
IF(DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1)<$C2:$C3+0,IF($C2:$C3+0<DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))),$C2:$C3+0,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))+1)),DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1)),

IF(DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1)<$D2:$D3+0,IF($D2:$D3+0<DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))),$D2:$D3+0,DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),DAY(EOMONTH($B$9,0))+1)),DATE(YEAR($B$9),MONTH($B$9),1))

))}
```

The above should work and it should take care of the negative numbers. Essentially it ensures that both dates are capped at the start and the end of the specified month (specified by the $B$9 cell). When actually specifying the days as the beginning or the end of the month, I had to add an extra day to the end of the month to avoid counting when there was actually no day included in the month.

I have not extensively tested it, but feel free to play around with it and feedback back to me. I splitted the formula accross lines for better visibility, but it is a small monster :)